# Datatable column filter multiselect with unique value once clicked

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I used the following code to populate a table with multiselect filters on each columns and it works just fine : [multiselect columns filters table exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/p1261jby/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
initComplete: function() {
  this.api().columns().every(function() {
    var column = this;
    //added class "mymsel"
    var select = $('<select class="mymsel" multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
        }).toArray().join('|');

        column
          .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
    });
  });
  //select2 init for .mymsel class
  $(".mymsel").select2();
}
```

});
});

However, when I select a value in a random column filter, the other filters offers the list of all possibles values instead of the distinct ones based on the previous filter.

Is there a way to do this ?